# Neither questions, nor answers

Tags: discussion

I just read a sentence that used *nor* in a way that I found strange (i.e. it seems ungrammatical to me), so I wanted to ask a question about it. Dutifully, I searched if such a question had been asked before, and the answer is yes, many times! However, none of the answers (there are too many questions for me to read all of them at the moment) answer **my** question. Can we get a single canonical question and answer as to how to use *nor*? Additionally, is there any way of reducing the amount of noise about this word?

Comment: Yes, but be very accurate in explaining why your question is different from those asked before,  or why the answers posted don't address your issue.

Comment: To help you in your quest... because there might be an older post that asks about the same thing so best search thoroughly before posting a new question https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/can-searches-be-more-productive-on-se

Comment: Or if the answers don't actually answer the question, flag them. And you can offer a bounty.

Comment: Plus, the OP is saying that the answers for the other questions are not answering the question he wants to ask.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I said if an answer doesn't actually try to answer the question you flag it, with, obviously, the Not An Answer flag. That's different from a wrong answer which you just downvote.

Comment: @curiousdannii That means: a question posted as answer, a comment asking the OP for information, a comment saying the user has the same problem, a comment saying _thanks_. An answer given from a user that didn't understand the question should not be flagged. I doubt the OP here found 3 questions which answers that aren't answers.

Comment: @kiam I don't know where you've got that idea, but it's well established across the network that "answers" which don't attempt to answer the actual question but instead answer a different question or go on a tangent should be tagged as NAA. I've had thousands of successful tags on such answers.

Comment: @curiousdannii No, Answers that answer a different question should not be flagged; those are included in _an altogether wrong answer_. I also have thousands of successful flags, but not because I flagged an answer given from a user who doesn't understand the question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yep, see [the second answer to that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292391/256282)

Comment: @curiousdannii Sure, but look at the examples: _What is the capital of Brazil?_ _The capital of Argentina is Buenos Aires._ That is **not** a user that misunderstood the question, which is what I am talking of. Anyway, the OP here is talking of answers for other questions that don't answer the question he would ask. Thinking it means there are answers not answering the question for which they are posted is understanding something completely different.

Comment: In other words: _I found similar questions, but none of the answers given there are the answer for the question I have._

Comment: By the way, moderators can mark a flag as useful, even if it was wrong. If a user would flag as _not an answer_ an answer that is spam, I (as moderator) would not mark it as not helpful, since it helped me in blocking a spammer. So, the number of helpful flags cannot be used to say _I surely understand how to use flags_.

Comment: To answer the question, I am not sure it is possible to make a canonical question. You found different questions with answers that don't answer your question. I take there are too nuances to make a good canonical question.